# Изменение текста после нажатия на кнопку

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

При нажатии на кнопку текст в QLineEdit должен меняться

```
class LineEdit : public QLineEdit {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    LineEdit(QWidget* widg):QLineEdit(widg){
    }
public slots:
    void rename(){
        this->setText("New Text");
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget widg;
    LineEdit line(&widg);
    QPushButton butt("but",&widg);
    QObject::connect(butt,SIGNAL(clicked ()),line,SLOT(rename()));
    widg.show();
    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

**no matching function for call to 'connect'** что это значит?

Пробовал наследоваться от QObject - тоже самое

Answer (score 2):

Вы забыли амперсанды:

```
QObject::connect(&butt..., &line...);
```

Comment: А как передать в функцию rename() из main()  что-либо при срабатывании сигнала?

Comment: Сигнал посылает не main, а в QPushButton. Поэтому передать должен именно он. Можно определить сигнал, который передает значение в LineEdit. Сформулируй более четко.